# @Sapphire/shapeshift DiscordJS - Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint 'object'

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord.js

I've got a discordJS (v14) bot that I'm starting (using typescript), and when I try to build it I get the following error:

```
node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.d.ts:590:44 - error TS2344: Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint 'object'.

590 declare type SchemaOf<T> = ObjectValidator<T>;
                                               ~

  node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.d.ts:590:23
    590 declare type SchemaOf<T> = ObjectValidator<T>;
                              ~
    This type parameter might need an `extends object` constraint.

node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.d.ts:641:65 - error TS2344: Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint 'object'.

641     object<T>(shape: MappedObjectValidator<T>): ObjectValidator<T, UndefinedToOptional<T>>;
                                                                    ~

  node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.d.ts:641:12
    641     object<T>(shape: MappedObjectValidator<T>): ObjectValidator<T, UndefinedToOptional<T>>;
                   ~
    This type parameter might need an `extends object` constraint.


Found 2 errors in the same file, starting at: node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.d.ts:590
```

My index.ts looks like this (yes its basic, but trying to figure out this error)

```
import "dotenv/config";
import "reflect-metadata";
import { Client, GatewayIntentBits } from 'discord.js';

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
  ]
});

client.login(process.env["DISCORD_TOKEN"]);
```

My package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "my-discord-bot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My Discord Bot",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "myself",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "cleanup": "rm -f -r ./dist/",
    "build": "yarn cleanup && tsc",
    "watch": "yarn cleanup && tsc -w",
    "serve": "node ./dist/index.js",
    "register": "node ./dist/register-commands.js",
    "lint": "eslint . -ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx",
    "format": "prettier --write \"./src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": ""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@sentry/integrations": "^7.13.0",
    "@sentry/node": "^7.13.0",
    "@sentry/tracing": "^7.13.0",
    "anti-phish-advanced": "^1.1.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "chrono-node": "^2.4.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.3",
    "discord.js": "^14.3.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.2",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "fuse.js": "^6.6.2",
    "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "steamid": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "*": ["types/*"]
        },

        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "module": "es2020",
        "target": "es2020",
        // "lib": ["es2020"],
        "moduleResolution": "node",

        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "allowJs": false,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,

        "types": ["node", "reflect-metadata"],
        "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]
    },
    "include": ["./src/**/*"],
    "exclude": ["**/node_modules", "**/__tests__/*", "**/tests/"]
}
```

A yarn why on the erroring package

```
yarn why v1.22.19
[1/4] Why do we have the module "@sapphire/shapeshift"...?
[2/4] Initialising dependency graph...
[3/4] Finding dependency...
[4/4] Calculating file sizes...
=> Found "@sapphire/shapeshift@3.5.1"
info Reasons this module exists
   - "discord.js#@discordjs#builders" depends on it
   - Hoisted from "discord.js#@discordjs#builders#@sapphire#shapeshift"
```

Does anyone know if there is anything that I'm doing that might be causing the issue? and how I might fix it? (short of just not using typescript)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/sapphiredev/shapeshift/issues/193

Need to force resolution of the package to a higher version.

Using yarn (as I am) is easy, just add to package.json

```
resolutions: {
  "@sapphire/shapeshift": "^3.6.0"
}
```